# Drop down menu CSS3 position

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

If you hover over the `User` menu, then the menu shows up at left = 0. But, it should show up exactly under the `User` 'button'. How can I accomplish this? (only CSS3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this rule to your CSS:

```
.menu > li {
    position: relative;
}
```

**Explanation:** if you specify `position: absolute` on an element, `top` and `left` will be relative to the first parent element that has any `position` other than `static`. If no element like that is found, it will be relative to the page (like in your case). Specifying `position: relative` is the easiest solution because the element won't be taken out of the document flow.

Comment: help me again, but in my menu, i need to use `position:absolute`