# Arrange CSS3 dropdown menu

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, menuitem

I tried with various settings for display and position but I don't know how to arrange the subitems in my future dropdown menu. They overlap with the other menuitems and don't stay in place where they should. Unfortunately even [this question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760601/drop-down-menu-css3) couldn't help me.

This is my CSS code:

```
#menu ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #FF0000;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
display: block;
float: left;
position:relative; }

#menu ul li a:hover {
background-color: #0000FF; }

#menu ul li ul li a {
clear: left;
background-color: #6F0;
font-size: 10px;
display: block;
position: absolute; }
```

I tried combined selectors like these

```
#menu ul li a + #menu ul li ul li a { }

li.page_item > li.page_item { }
```

but they did not work either.

Edit:
Here is some HTML/PHP code. It's a wordpress template, now I think I should have mentioned that before ...

```
            <div id="menu" role="navigation">
            <?php /* Navigation menu. */ ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu' => 'Categories', 'container_class' => 'main-menu-class',
                                    'container_id' => 'main-menu-id', 'theme_location'  => 'header', 'show_home' => true)); ?>
        </div> <!-- menu -->
```

And the rendered HTML code is:

```
<div id="menu" role="navigation">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item">
<a title="Home" href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-40">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?page_id=40">Cupcake Ipsum</a>
<ul class="children">
<li class="page_item page-item-388">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?page_id=388">Red Velvet Cupcake</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-390">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?page_id=390">Mango Cupcake</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-392">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?page_id=392">Chocolate Cupcake</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-43">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?page_id=43">Bacon Ipsum</a>
<ul class="children">
<li class="page_item page-item-405">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?page_id=405">Bacon Pancakes</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-45">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?page_id=45">Veggie Ipsum</a>
<ul class="children">
<li class="page_item page-item-397">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?page_id=397">Tomato</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-399">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?page_id=399">Lettuce</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-401">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?page_id=401">Broccoli</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-403">
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/wordpress/?page_id=403">Onion</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put some html here. Paste the output on jsfiddle.net and give us a link

Comment: I edited my question and added the HTML/PHP code.

Comment: *Rendered* HTML would be good, rather than PHP. This lets people play around with it in online sandboxes.

Comment: Sorry guys, it's the first wordpress template I create. I added the rendered HTML code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes to your CSS to fix the overlap issues.

```
#menu ul li a {
  float: none; /* no need for float */
}

#menu ul li ul li a {
 position: static; /* no need for absolute positioning here */
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li ul {
 position: absolute; 
}

.menu li:not(:hover) ul {
 display: none; 
}
```

And here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/aloreh/1/edit

Your general problem is that you're putting `position: absolute` and `position: relative` on the wrong things. It's good that you're applying all your link styling to the actual link elements, but you need to apply the positioning to the lists and the list items.

So, the first level list items need to have `position: relative`. This allows submenus to be positioned relative to the first level items. Then the submenu `ul`s will have `position: absolute` so that they don't reflow the page when they appear on hover.

Comment: thank you, that helped me a lot. And I did not know that a not(:hover) selector exists, that's awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

If you give an element absolute positioning

```
position: absolute;
```

It doesn't know where to go until you explicitly tell it where you want it to appear on the page.

Change this fiddle until it does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/hillsons/LUqpM/